# The number of two-letter sequences of length $15$ with runs of consecutive letters of given length

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

> Determine the number of unique sequences of length
>   15, consisting of x's and y's, and which contain either 10 consecutive x's or 5 consecutive
>   y's. (`xyyyxyyyyyyyyyy' is an example of a sequence which should be counted).

I'm currently stuck on this question and have been getting some very large answers (e.g 46078) that I don't believe can exist.

Any assistance with the following question would be great:

Answer (score 1):

The strings with 5 consecutive $a$s can be counted as

- beginning with at least 5 $a$, i.e. $aaaaa$ followed by arbitrary stuff: $2^5=32$
- beginning with $k$ arbitrary letters, followed by $baaaaa$, followed by $4-k$ arbitrary (so $0\le k\le 4$): $5\cdot 2^4$.

That makes $112$ seqeuences contaiing $aaaaa$ somewhere. There are also $112$ seqeunces with $bbbbb$. WE have to subtract those counted in both parts, i.e. $aaaaabbbbb$ and $bbbbbaaaaa$. So th etotal is $222$.

Comment: Judging by the example given it's at least 5 consecutive, does this working include that?

for example: "babaaaaaab" can be counted

Answer (score 1):

Say that the *earliest* position at which you finish a run of $5$ is $k$.  If $k=5$, there are $2$ choices for the run letter and $32$ choices for the remaining letters.  If $k=6,7,8,9,10$, there are $2$ choices for the run letter and $16$ choices for the remaining letters (the letter at $k-5$ must differ from the run letter, but the other four are free).  For $k=10$, this count includes $a^5 b^5$ and $b^5 a^5$, whose earliest runs actually finish at $k=5$; subtract those two.  The result is: $64+5\cdot 32 - 2=222$ possibilities.